# Migrate Oracle SQL query with ROWNUM into PostgreSQL HQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, hql

I have the following Oracle SQL query:

```
SELECT user FROM global_users user WHERE user.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND user.description IS NOT NULL AND user.updatedGoodsDate BETWEEN '2024-03-10 20:09:53' AND '2024-03-10 20:09:53'
AND ROWNUM <= 13
```

I tried to edit the query into Postgres with Spring Data JPA:

```
    @Query("SELECT user FROM global_users user WHERE user.status = :status
    AND user.description IS NOT NULL AND user.updatedGoodsDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
    List<Users> findTopUsers(@Param("status") TransactionStatus status,
      @Param("startDate") OffsetDateTime start, @Param("endDate") OffsetDateTime end, @Param("count") long count);
```

But I can't use LIMIT clause in Postgre. Is there some way to edit the query and get the same result?

For example can this be implemented with a subquery?

Test project: https://github.com/rcbandit111/oracle_rownum_pg_migration_poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/portal/account/platform/repository/DataRepository.java

Comment: Note that your original query has an issue, because it is missing an `ORDER BY` clause.  If you had an `ORDER BY` clause you could just filter the collection on the Java side.

Comment: ok, `ORDER BY clause` can be added. Can you show me migrated query for PosgreSQL please?

Comment: You can use [LIMIT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) clause

Comment: hm... I tried but I use HQL. I can't use native query.

Comment: Your Oracle query is not valid as `USER` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612) (both in Oracle and in ANSI SQL). Also `'2024-03-10 20:09:53'` is not a `DATE` data-type; it is a string literal pretending to be a date. Oracle may implicitly try to convert it to a date but if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter does not match then the conversion would fail (and any user can change their own session parameters at any time so you should never rely on implicit conversions)

Comment: Please see the test project into the link.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12 and, at least PostgreSQL 9, both RDBMS support the `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` syntax:

```
SELECT "USER"
FROM   global_users
WHERE  status = 'ACTIVE'
AND    description IS NOT NULL
AND    updatedGoodsDate BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53'
                            AND TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53'
-- ORDER BY something
FETCH FIRST 13 ROWS ONLY
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE global_users (
  "USER" VARCHAR(10),
  status VARCHAR(8),
  description VARCHAR(20),
  updatedGoodsDate TIMESTAMP
)

INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Alice', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Beryl', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Carol', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Debra', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Emily', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Fiona', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Grace', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Haley', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Irene', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Julie', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Kelly', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Lydia', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Megan', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
INSERT INTO global_users ("USER", status, description, updatedGoodsDate)
VALUES ('Naomi', 'ACTIVE', 'X', TIMESTAMP '2024-03-10 20:09:53');
```

Outputs:

| USER |
| --- |
| Alice |
| Beryl |
| Carol |
| Debra |
| Emily |
| Fiona |
| Grace |
| Haley |
| Irene |
| Julie |
| Kelly |
| Lydia |
| Megan |

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aopg0Wvm) [PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hgd5sm8C)